# How to overcome this issue : 'fatal error: pyhelper.hpp: No such file or directory' in c++ program?

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to call python module in c++ program,

I used '#include <pyhelper.hpp>', but iam getting error:

"fatal error: pyhelper.hpp: No such file or directory"

So please suggest me the solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: add the path of the file to your include path

Comment: You may have to adjust the include paths for compilation. You may get similar problems linking.